# merging two rows separately

Tags: excel, vba

When I do the following in vba, the two rows merge into one. I want to have two separate, merged rows, can anyone help ??

```
Range("A" & 1 & ":I" & 1).MergeCells = True
Range("A" & 2 & ":I" & 2).MergeCells = True
```

Comment: But those will not merge Rows 1 and 2 together unless one cell from row 1 is merged with row 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to my comment try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Range("A" & 1 & ":I" & 2).MergeCells = False

    Range("A" & 1 & ":I" & 1).MergeCells = True
    Range("A" & 2 & ":I" & 2).MergeCells = True
End Sub
```